# Different code(.java file) for different platform?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, ffmpeg

I have a code where image data is passed from bitmap to FFmpeg frame recorder and converted to a video. But i need to make small changes while running it on LG G3(armv7) from Asus zenfone 5(x86).

Following are the class variables that create the issue:(declared under, class Main Activity)

inputWidth = 1024;

inputHeight = 650;

Following is the method where the issue occurs:

```
 byte [] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap bitmap) {

    int [] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];

    bitmap.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);

    byte [] yuv = new byte[inputWidth*inputHeight*3/2];
    encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);

    return yuv;
}

void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    int yIndex = 0;
    int uvIndex = frameSize;

    int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

            a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
            R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
            B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

            // well known RGB to YUV algorithm
            Y = ( (  66 * R + 129 * G +  25 * B + 128) >> 8) +  16;
            U = ( ( -38 * R -  74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            V = ( ( 112 * R -  94 * G -  18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

            // NV21 has a plane of Y and interleaved planes of VU each sampled by a factor of 2
            //    meaning for every 4 Y pixels there are 1 V and 1 U.  Note the sampling is every other
            //    pixel AND every other scanline.
            yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
            if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((V<0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((U<0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
            }

            index ++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Working CODE:**

LG G3 :I can use the above variables at any place in the code to get the required output.
Bitmap size returned = 2734200

Asus Zenfone 5: Except at creating the bitmap, I have to use everywhere else bitmap.getHeight() and bitmap.getWidth(), to get the required output.

Surprisingly here Bitmap size returned = 725760 (So its not setting according to set bitmap parameters?)

**INCORRECT CODE:**

LG G3 : IF i use bitmap.getHeight() and bitmap.getWidth(), i get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length = 102354 , index = 102354. @getNV21 method

Asus Zenfone 5 : If i use inputWidth , inputHeight i get 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width() @getNV21 method

How can i generalize the above code for both phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this you can use a [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

Strategy pattern allows you to change algorithms during runtime based on your environment. Basically you define an interface for your strategy. Something like this:

```
interface MyStrategy {
    byte[] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap bitmap);
}
```

Then you make multiple implementations of your interface, one for LG, one for Asus and, for example, one for all other devices (device neutral):

```
class MyStrategyForLG implements MyStrategy {

    public byte[] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap bitmap) {
        // ...
    }

}


class MyStrategyForAsus implements MyStrategy {

    public byte[] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap bitmap) {
        // ...
    }

}


class DefaultMyStrategy implements MyStrategy {

    public byte[] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap bitmap) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

You can create a factory for `MyStrategy` so you can avoid use of if-else in your `MainActivity`. Something like this:

```
class MyStrategyFactory {

    public void createMyStrategy() {
        // ...
        if ( deviceIsAsus ) {
            return new MyStrategyForAsus();
        }
        if ( deviceIsLg ) {
            return new MyStrategyForLG();
        }
        return new DefaultMyStrategy();
    }
}
```

In your `MainActivity` you can invoke your strategy like this:

```
// ...
MyStrategy strategy = new MyStrategyFactory().createMyStrategy();
byte[] bytes = strategy.getNV21(width, height, image);
// ...
```

The advantage of this method is that you do not need to modify calling site when you add another device, for example, when you notice that Samsung is also a bit weird. Instead you implement `MyStrategyForSamsung` and change the factory to return it when the code is executed on Samsung device.